# MySQL SELECT Conditional CONCAT

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

I have a database which basically holds addresses

The table (tblAddress) looks like this...

```
housename    | housenumber | address1    | address2        | address3 | town      | postcode
Banana House |          29 | Acacia Road | Yellow Skin Way |          | Nuttytown | W1 1MP
```

When I search the database based on a postcode I want to be able to return and result like this...

```
Banana House,29 Acacia Road,Yellow Skin Way,Nuttytown,W1 1MP
```

So I need the housenumber concatenated with address1 IF address1 is populated. If not then concat with address2 or address3. Then the rest of the address to follow as per the example.

I tried using IF and CASE statements but can't seem to get anywhere near the output I'm after.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding few concat operations.

Check below code it should work.

```
SELECT CONCAT(housename, CONCAT(" ",CONCAT(housenumber, CONCAT(" ",CONCAT_WS(' ,', 
                  NULLIF(address1, ''), 
                  NULLIF(address2, ''), 
                  NULLIF(address3, ''),
                  NULLIF(town, ''),
                  NULLIF(postcode, '')))))) AS concatedAddress FROM tblAddress;
```

Comment: I'm not waiting for the best answer, I'm testing as they come in, and they're coming in fast. I'll respond as soon as I've finished testing and can confirm the correct one.

Comment: I've now tested this and can confirm that it works. It just needs a slight modification to add a comma after the housename. Thank you for your time in resolving this for me. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat_ws()` (concatenation with separator) along with `nullif()`

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', NULLIF(housename, ''), 
                      NULLIF(housenumber, ''),  
                      NULLIF(address1, ''), 
                      NULLIF(address2, ''), 
                      NULLIF(address3, ''),
                      NULLIF(town, ''),
                      NULLIF(postcode, '')
       ) AS address FROM tblAddress
```

Comment: That will result in  `Banana House,29,Acacia Road...` topicstarter asked for `Banana House,29 Acacia Road...`

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
 SELECT CONCAT_WS ( ", ",
    housename,
    CONCAT(housenumber, CONCAT_WS (", ", NULLIF(address1, ''), NULLIF(address2, ''), NULLIF(address3, ''))),
    town,
    postcode) AS address
FROM tblAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
       housename
      ,CONCAT( housenumber, CONCAT(' ', COALESCE(address1, '')), CONCAT(' ', COALESCE(address2, '')), CONCAT(' ', COALESCE(address3, '')) ) AS address
      ,town
      ,postcode 
FROM tblAddress;
```