# MySQL Fuzzy Search across all fields for autocomplete

Tags: mysql, fuzzy

Note this is a follow-up to a previously asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584904/mysql-select-conditional-concat), but on a completely different issue and hence a new question.

I have a database which basically holds addresses

The table (tblAddress) looks like this...

```
housename    | housenumber | address1    | address2        | address3 | town      | postcode
Banana House |          29 | Acacia Road | Yellow Skin Way |          | Nuttytown | W1 1MP
```

I've implemented the solution from the previous question, which now works as expected, and for which I'm very grateful. However I would now like to do something a little more ambitious!

On a front-end web page, I'd like to provide an autocomplete text input field which provides a search facility of the address database. I'd like the user to be able to start typing any part of an address, whether it's the housename, number, postcode, address2 etc etc, and for the autocomplete to fetch the top 10 best matches.

Using LIKE is incredibly slow sometimes taking a minute to return anything meaningful. The database is indexed on all fields right now using BTREE.

Do I need some sort of fuzzy search method?

I've read many articles on the matter but I'm struggling to find anything that makes enough sense to apply to what I'm trying to achieve.

Besides the actual method, the speed is very important. I assume the indexing will be crucial to this as much as the method.

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps consider looking into [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: A `like '%...%'` search cannot use indexes - hence it is slow. Full text search via MySQL's own fulltext search functionality or via special search engines like sphinx would be more efficient.

Comment: Agree with @Shadow using something like Sphinx, Solr or Elastic Search would be much more efficient, although may require some additional resource and bit of learning curve if not familiar.

Comment: Thanks, for these suggestions. I did read up on Elastic Search and Solr but would require moving in a different direction and a learning curve like you say. I will look into it now though.